# Libertarian perspective: America's gun laws and the Florida high school shooting

Tags: united-states, libertarianism, guns

Every time such massacres happen, leftists try to push the gun control debate using emotional appeal and libertarians try to defend the right to bear arms based on reason (ex: tyrannical governments, right to self-defense, ...). However, these libertarian arguments do not seem to convince the average citizen.

**Question**
Are there other arguments (or tactics) that libertarians could use in order to convince the average citizen to support the right to bear arms?

Comment: Setting up your question with the assumption that libetarians are "right" suggests that this question is more about pushing your point of view rather than seeking an answer.

Comment: @JamesK > "[...] pushing your point of view rather than seeking an answer." You've missed the point. The question is not whether the right to bear arms is right or wrong. Instead, is how libertarians could convince more people in the society.

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question, or others may miss the point too.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as primarily opinion based because how it has scoped the approach to finding other arguments for libertarians. As worded, there isn't an objective measure available.

Comment: @DrunkCynic _"there isn't an objective measure available."_ As most of the political issues.

Comment: @DrunkCynic - psychology and sociology provides pretty objective answers (or at least, "good subjective")

Comment: I think it would be worth reviewing the [help], and notably what questions are [on-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Especially given the polarization of this topic in America, I don't believe a question like this can be answered objectively using impartial facts and references.  Also relevant, from our sister site Stack Overflow: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: There is a main argument to counter: That those mass shootings are happening far too often in the United States compared with other, similar countries. For example, this shooting was the 19th incident in schools this year alone (and it is February). In Germany, it didn't happen for years. There is something going fundamentally wrong, and if it is not the lacking gun control, you have to give a different convincing explanation. Comparing two US states will not help when comparison with Europe, Japan, Canada etc. will disprove any such argument.

Comment: @Nebr _"this shooting was the 19th incident in schools this year alone"_ [No, there haven’t been 18 school shootings in 2018. That number is flat wrong.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/no-there-havent-been-18-school-shooting-in-2018-that-number-is-flat-wrong/2018/02/15/65b6cf72-1264-11e8-8ea1-c1d91fcec3fe_story.html?utm_term=.1dddbdeecfcd)

Comment: @MarkMessa Thank you for the correction, I didn't know that. However, there still remain 5 school shootings in roughly 6 weeks, and several more incidents which are also very uncommon in other countries. But lets only stick to the 5 incidents. Extrapolating this still makes it several dozen times more likely that you become involved in a school shooting in the USA compared to most European countries. You may still be able to discuss the numbers a bit, but the core argument keeps valid. And you will not be able to convince a gun control promoter by just discarding the argument.

Comment: @Nebr _"there still remain 5 school shootings in roughly 6 weeks"_ I recommend that you stick only with the massacres (ie: Florida, Rancho Tehama, ...). Otherwise, if you really wanna count this way, I'm not sure if USA has more 'school shooting' than Rio de Janeiro city (which was recently declared under military intervention due to out-of-control crimes).

Comment: @MarkMessa Since you essentially confuted yourself by showing that the US has a comparable school shooting rate to a country where crime is out of control and the government faces serious corruption issues, I don't need any further argumentation here. Since you asked how to convince a gun control advocate: THAT is not the way.

Comment: @Nebr _"a country where crime is out of control and the government faces serious corruption issues"_ You've forgot to mention, but Brazil also has strict gun prohibition.

Comment: @Nebr _"THAT is not the way."_ Agree, you should change the way you count school shootings. Instead of using the statistics the aforementioned article already showed to be misleading, take a look at Wikipedia which seems to be more reasonable.

Comment: @MarkMessa Do you want to know how to convince people with other opinions or do you just want to relieve yourself by calling them "unreasonable" as often as you can, maybe hoping that you can intimidate them that way? Answer this question: Why is the US the only state in the Western world where such shootings occur in such a frequent manner? Really, no one cares for Brazil, or the Philippines, or some other state with a major corruption problem. I bet the killing rate in Taliban controlled regions is much higher independent of gun control, but that doesn't help you convince anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general answer is "no" on "arguments". Facts don't convince people, or rather convince people far less effectively than emotions and stories do.

As such, the best approach is to forget (a) facts and (b) abstract concepts; and instead counter with what works. In case of someone wishing to argue for gun rights, possible approaches would be:

- Stories about people who were saved from becoming victims of violent crime because they were armed
- Stories about people who were threatened, filed a complaint with the justice system, and [were murdered because police were late/not present/didn't take complaint seriously](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/1245/115). This is an especially effective counter against the abstract "let the police protect you" counter argument against gun rights. For extra weight, explain how *police are legally **not** obligated to prevent anyone from being a victim of a crime* (for all those 10 people in the whole country who pay attention to facts :)
- Stories about whole people/groups who were disarmed and suffered massively being unable to resist armed groups or government violence (there's plenty of those throughout human history).

---

Additionally, according to [Moral Foundations theory](http://www.moralfoundations.org); conservatives and liberals are swayed not necessarily by different facts; but by different *framing* of the facts.
Since the opponents of gun rights tend to be "lefter" side, the arguments - to be effective - need to be framed in terms of "Fairness" and "Care" angles:

- Disarming people is unfair to the poor. The rich can afford to live in gated communities, hire bodyguards, and pay more taxes for good policing. The poor have to deal with violent crime without those benefits (extra bonus if you use the term "privilege" considering specific sides arguing this specific debate).

  This isn't some theoretical mind bender from a fringe libertarian's mind. Black Panthers were far more pro-2nd-amendment than most convinced NRA members today.
- Disarming people is unfair to ANYONE who is physically smaller are thus less able to win a physical conflict (but disproportionately affects women, who are physically smaller/weaker on average). There's a reason Colt was called "The Great Equalizer"

Comment: _" forget (a) facts and (b) abstract concepts; and instead counter with what works. "_ Perfect, you've got the point. I hope libertarians read your answer and try to employ new ways to persuade the average citizen. Unfortunately, only a small group of people is persuaded by reasoning. For the far majority of people, reason is too much complicated.

Comment: I would just point out that the shooter brought a gun into a “gun free zone”. The debate should be why the security guards did not block the entrance of the shooter instead of pushing gun prohibition for the **entire** country.

Comment: Related to the framing thing... it's worth pointing out that [the civil rights leaders relied *heavily* on the 2nd amendment](http://reason.com/blog/2017/10/05/how-the-second-amendment-helped-activist), largely because that was the only protection they had against segregationist law enforcement officials in the south who otherwise might well have murdered them all.  Not a stretch to suggest that the civil rights movement owes a good portion of its success to the 2nd amendment, and ponder the implications of that going forward...

Comment: @HopelessN00b _"the civil rights leaders relied heavily on the 2nd amendment"_ Very important point (+1). However, I don't think this is gonna convince the average citizen to support the right to bear arms.

Comment: @MarkMessa ...but it is an argument, or a point that appeals to the typical liberal, and proves as a good counter point to the "guns are only people-killing machines" sentiment that's common on the left.  And, not to put too fine a point on it, is an example of guns helping liberals when and where the government wanted them dead.

Comment: @HopelessN00b _"but it is an argument"_ Yes, I agree with you. It is a good argument and will help the debate in favor of the 2nd amendment. However, I don't see this as the pivotal point in the debate; most people will still choose their sides based on emotion (or other shortcut) instead of deep reasoning.

Comment: @MarkMessa Depends who you're discussing it with, I'd imagine. The African Americans in my social circle that I've shared that narrative with have mostly found it to be an *extremely* compelling argument, even (or maybe particularly) those who are registered Democrats and *used to* strongly favor strict gun-control measures. On a related tangent, pointing out the harm the federal government does to black communities by limiting education options for black children has changed many of their minds on the "school choice" debate. Generic arguments don't work; tailored arguments might change minds.

Comment: @HopelessN00b _"The African Americans in my social circle [...] found it to be an extremely compelling"_ Perfect! You've got the idea. I agree with you this is a compelling argument for several African Americans. There is a strong emotional side attached to it which I didn't see initially. Any other ideas for the Non-African Americans?

Comment: @MarkMessa Nothing beyond what's in the answer, and my little addendum about tailoring your argument to your audience.  Understand what appeals to them on an emotional level (because facts don't convince people), and make your case accordingly.

Comment: @HopelessN00b _"Nothing beyond what's in the answer"_ Is it possible to do something (ex: some kind of regulation) that would reduce such massacres and still would not infringe the right to bear arms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73280/discussion-between-hopelessn00b-and-mark-messa).

Comment: @HopelessN00b I'm really not a fan of chat, so I'm gonna answer anyway the question. People have the natural right to defend themselves, therefore, governments should not infringe the right to keep and bear arms. However, private places can bypass that. There is no problem if the owner of a bar choose for a gun free zone; customers will ultimately decide whether this place is safe or not. Therefore, it is the owner responsibility to check if people are carrying guns or not.

Comment: @userLTK - argument from authority - logical fallacy (and to use another logical fallacy on you, Supreme court also ruled in Dredd vs Scott. Which doesn't magically make that ruling overwrite the unerlying ethical and moral considerations)

Comment: @userLTK _"The supreme court know the constitution a little bit better than you."_ _Argumentum Ad-hominem:_ Shoot the messenger fallacy

Comment: @MarkMessa   (edited to take out that sentence), yes, it's not fair to say they know laws better, but the fact is, the supreme court disagrees with you on the law.    A concervative supreme court ruled that cities and states have the right to ban guns for public safety to a degree. They can't ban guns ownership entirely, but they can create gun restrictions.  The premise that government can't do that is a false premise.  You can believe that they shouldn't, but you shouldn't state your opinion as absolute.   There is lots of legit legal debate that you're just dismissing.

Answer (score 6):

#### Political support for reforming gun laws

It is unclear to me that the average citizen is unconvinced to leave gun laws largely alone.  Note that the average citizen is not voting for candidates who favor more restrictive gun laws.  Republicans currently control all three elected portions of the government (and the unelected Supreme Court).  Yes, Hillary Clinton won a plurality of the popular vote, but Donald Trump plus Gary Johnson won more votes than Clinton plus Jill Stein.

#### Polling

Another argument is that polling shows that citizens support various reform proposals when asked.  But this support tends to be soft.  Very few people vote based on that.

*All gun sales should go through a background check.*

Most people support this.  The Manchin-Toomey compromise was based on this.  It was rejected by the National Rifle Association.  The public reason was that it had insufficient protections against a national gun registry.  Most NRA-friendly politicians voted against it, so it did not pass.

The average citizen is for this in principle, but I haven't seen a big hew and cry over it.  It has not passed and would not affect most of the newsworthy events.  If it were to pass, it would have minimal effect on gun rights.  It is very seldom that someone legally obtains a gun without being able to pass a background check.

*Ban assault weapons.*

This is a bit tricky.  One simple argument is to simply point out that anything that actually is an "assault weapon" is already under severe restrictions.  Note that actual assault rifles are almost never used in crimes.  Instead, people tend to buy lookalike guns like the AR-15.

Another argument is that we tried that.  It didn't work.  There are other guns that perform the same that are still available, as the differences between an "assault weapon" and any other rifle are mostly [cosmetic](https://reason.com/blog/2018/02/15/an-assault-weapon-ban-wont-stop-mass-sho):

> The latest version of Feinstein's bill covers any semiautomatic rifle with a detachable magazine if it also has a pistol grip or forward grip, a grenade launcher or rocket launcher, a barrel shroud, a threaded barrel, or a folding, telescoping, or detachable stock.

No mass shooting has used a grenade launcher or a rocket launcher, as the ammunition is not generally available.  Banning those is a solution in search of a problem.

Semiautomatic is the most common type of gun in civilian use.  (Individuals in the military use fully automatic weapons.  Plus there are larger weapons that don't fit well in the categories used by weapons that can be operated by a single individual.)

For the rest of it, all those things are within the capability of a 3D printer these days.  Yes, actual 3D-printed guns don't work that well.  But those aren't 3D-printed guns.  They're parts frequently made of plastic or wood.  They are exactly the kind of things that can be 3D-printed.  The hard part to 3D-print is the receiver.  The receiver is not restricted by the ban, so people can just buy any workable receiver and build an "assault weapon" around it.

#### Ineffective

As I said earlier, very few people obtain weapons legally that cannot pass a background check.  So an expanded background check system would have minimal effect.  The real problem is that crazy people are not getting put into the background check system as too crazy to have a gun.

We used to have an assault weapons ban.  There is no evidence that it stopped gun violence.  Most gun violence is with handguns, not any type of rifle.  More than 60% of all firearm homicides and 90% of homicides where the type of firearm was identified are committed with handguns.

#### Misleading arguments

One thing to watch for in anti-gun arguments is misleading switches.  They will talk about gun deaths, gun homicides, and total suicides all together, switching as necessary to grab the right statistic.  Consider:

1. Gun deaths are highest in states with the most guns.

   This is true, but only because gun suicides are higher in states with the most guns.  Two out of three gun deaths are by suicide.  Only one out of three are homicide.  Only about 4% are something else.

   They will often state this in such a way that someone might think that gun homicides are highest in states with the most guns.  However, that's [not true](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/no-states-with-higher-gun-ownership-dont-have-more-gun-murders/article/2573353).
2. Reducing the number of guns reduces gun suicides.

   This is certainly true.  However, who cares?  If we're talking about reducing suicides, we should be talking about all suicides.  And there's no reason to think that reducing the number of guns will have a long term effect on suicides.

   In Australia, they confiscated all the semiautomatic guns.  This reduced the number of gun suicides the next year by more than would have been expected (Australia was in the middle of a ten year drop in gun suicides).  Two problems though.  First, the number of suicides by hanging was unexpectedly high that year.  Two, the number of gun suicides jumped the year after that, once people had time to replace their semiautomatics with revolvers and shotguns.  Overall, in the five years after the ban, gun suicides dropped by about as much as they had in the five years prior to the ban.

   Often cited as a great success for gun control, it as actually something of a fizzle.  Negligible effect on gun homicides, although neither Australia nor New Zealand have experience a mass shooting since then.  It's unclear why confiscating guns in Australia would have affected New Zealand.  Presumably they have something else in common.  Or random chance.

   In Japan, there are no gun suicides.  However, total suicides are higher per capita than in the United States.

#### Japan

If there is one country that has been really effective in preventing gun violence, it is Japan.  They have a complete ban on the sale of guns and ammunition.  Even organized crime doesn't try to use guns in Japan.

Consider how they did it though.  Obviously they don't have a second amendment.  But that's not the real advantage that Japan has.  They don't have an exclusionary rule (which derives from the fourth amendment).  So if a police officer sees a person with a gun run into a group of people, the officer can require the entire group to submit to searches.

In the United States, a police officer could only search the single person who had been carrying the gun.  If a police officer searched everyone, the possession charge would be thrown out as the search would be excluded as having insufficient basis.  The officer could only search with probable cause, and "one of them must have it" is not considered probably cause.

In Japan, if the search finds its target, then it was clearly justified.  The result takes precedence.

Even with the second amendment and widespread gun ownership, elimination of the exclusionary rule in the United States would allow police a much greater ability to control crime.  Some libertarians may find this too risky (libertarians generally favor the exclusionary rule and the fourth amendment), but this argument puts the onus on leftists to explain their support for a rule that contributes to gun violence.

#### Second amendment

Another argument is that the second amendment prevents many types of effective regulation.  In particular, regulations can't significantly reduce the number of guns in circulation.  All they can do is slow the rate at which guns are added to circulation.  This is because when a gun is banned currently, they can't take it away from existing owners.  So everyone that currently has the gun keeps it.  People just can't buy new ones in stores.

The argument here is that they should really focus on effective changes.  However, effective changes require repealing the second amendment.  So they should focus on that.

Comment: Brythan, a lot of important information in your answer (+1). However, I still don't think this is gonna convince the average citizen. Most people will not rationalize that deep in order to make a decision to which side to support. Therefore, any other idea of how to convince the average citizen?

Answer (score -3):

You may not like my answer, but the answer to your question is that libertarianism in its pure form, is a lie.   That doesn't mean that people can't vote libertarian or support libertarian ideas, but in the pure sense, there is no such thing as 100% libertarian.

One person's right to throw a party infringes against another person's right to peace and quiet.    One person's right to set up a manure business and make money infringes on his neighbors right to breath clean air.   One person's right to dig a mine and prospect for gold on his land, infringes on the right of everyone downstream of him to have clean stream water to use for cooking or fishing.   There is no such thing as no government, because people need laws and laws are written by government.

A person has a reasonable expectation that his son or daughter be safe in school and when a mentally challenged, angry 19 year old can walk into a store and buy an 3-4 round a second assault rifle with the intention of shooting as many high school kids as he can - that's a violation of the rights of everybody who wants to be safe.

The big gun control case that went to the supreme court, [Columbia vs Heller in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_v._Heller) actually came down on the side of the right with a (not unusual for the supreme court), 5/4 decision along party lines.

In the interest of brevity, I'll let [someone else do the summarizing](http://bigthink.com/risk-reason-and-reality/the-supreme-court-ruling-on-the-2nd-amendment-did-not-grant-an-unlimited-right-to-own-guns).

> There is no question that District of Columbia v. Heller was precisely
>   the sort of judicial activism the conservative justices of the Supreme
>   Court promised not to do. In a 5 to 4 decision those justices ruled
>   that the Second Amendment gives Americans the right to own guns for
>   personal self-defense, despite the amendment’s opening language - “A
>   well regulated militia being necessary to the security of a free
>   state, ” -  which pretty clearly says that gun ownership was
>   specifically preserved by the founding fathers in the interest of the
>   common defense against a tyrannical government (remember, this was the
>   issue on their minds back then). Gun rights advocates cheered. Gun
>   control advocates cried foul.
>
> But even though the 5-4 majority ruling makes an intellectual end run
>   around the language of the Second Amendment to get to their ruling,
>   they very clearly state that society (government, convened to
>   collectively protect us from what we can’t protect ourselves from as
>   individuals) has the right to, and legitimate interest in controlling
>   gun ownership, in several specific ways.
>
> On pp. 54 and 55, the majority opinion, written by conservative
>   bastion Justice Antonin Scalia, states:  “Like most rights, the right
>   secured by the Second Amendment is not unlimited…”. It is “…not a
>   right to keep and carry any weapon whatsoever in any manner whatsoever
>   and for whatever purpose.”
>
> “Nothing in our opinion should be taken to cast doubt on longstanding
>   prohibitions on the possession of firearms by felons and the mentally
>   ill, or laws forbidding the carrying of firearms in sensitive places
>   such as schools and government buildings, or laws imposing conditions
>   and qualifications on the commercial sale of arms.”
>
> “We also recognize another important limitation on the right to keep
>   and carry arms. Miller (an earlier case) said, as we have explained,
>   that the sorts of weapons protected were those “in common use at the
>   time”. We think that limitation is fairly supported by the historical
>   tradition of prohibiting the carrying of ‘dangerous and unusual
>   weapons.’ ”
>
> The court even recognizes a long-standing judicial precedent “to
>   consider prohibitions on carrying concealed weapons.”

So, long story short - local governments can restrict gun ownership and carry laws in the interest of national safety.   Citizens can and do vote for or against politicians based on their position on guns.   This is called democracy.   It's electing representatives to write laws, that can be challenged in the courts.   It's precisely how the constitution was meant to work.

You wrote:

> leftists try to push the gun control debate using emotional appeal and
>   libertarians try to defend the right to bear arms based on reason (ex:
>   tyrannical governments . . .

OK, "Tyranical governments" is an emotional argument, not a reasonable one, so lets get that out of the way.     But here's the thing.   There's no law against making an emotional argument.    Emotional arguments are legal and can even be valid.   You don't have to like them, but you should respect people's right to make them.  It's free speech.  It's self expression.

Two - you'll lever get everyone to agree with you.  You can ask people to agree, but the so called average citizen, will either agree with you or they won't.   All you can do is make your pitch and let the other side make theirs.

Three - a majority of Americans [don't think Assault Weapons should be legal to buy](https://www.npr.org/2017/10/13/557433452/poll-majorities-of-both-parties-favor-increased-gun-restrictions) and while different wording of that poll will get different answers (I know you can find [the opposite argument](http://news.gallup.com/poll/196658/support-assault-weapons-ban-record-low.aspx)) - never let it be said that I'm not fair.   One thing that's clear is against bump stocks, which the NRA still defends.  And the rights of Gun owners is very very very well represented in congress.  The rights of gun objectors (and it is a right to object to the sale of guns for safety reasons), they are not well represented.

> **Question** Are there other arguments (or tactics) that libertarians
>   could use in order to convince the average citizen to support the
>   right to bear arms

This is entirely opinion.

But my answer to you in general is to recognize that not everyone will agree with you, and democracy has to do its best when a citizenship is divided.   Your belief doesn't make you right in the eyes of others.

Comment: People who vote down should say why.   This is a recurring problem on this board.

Comment: @MarkMessa I answered your commentary.   I felt it was open for addressing.

Comment: _"I answered your commentary."_ Where is such answer? I'm not seeing anything new in this page ...

Comment: @MarkMessa  did you read it?

Comment: You so casually sweep aside the possibility of "tyranical governments" and then arrogantly conclude that the rationale behind your insane statement is self explanatory.  Please explain it.

Comment: @acpilot  It was a bad question, thinly disguised political commentary.    I gave commentary of the other side.   We don't have to agree, but we should allow discourse.     And "Tyranical governments", aka, run by a tyrant are certainly possible and there are many across the globe.    Much less likely in the American system of checks and balances, but I'm not sure what tyranny has to do with the question.   Regulation is not tyrannical.   Weighing keeping the guns out of the hands of people who are dangerous/psychotic against the right to bear arms is a question for the courts.

Comment: @acpilot  And calling my statement "insane" isn't specific.   If there's something specific I said that you disagree with, please say so, but keep in mind.   Disagreeing with me isn't proof that my statement is insane.   That's par for the course in the partisan world we live in, but you should try to do better and post more specifically.